# How do I code POST authenticated request to an API using python requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-requests

I am fairly new to coding in Python, and coding in general, and I am attempting to make an authenticated buy function to the Binance API.

From what I've gathered this is usually done using the curl method on Linux, I've tried to use `requests` instead in the Python library, and I keep getting an error 400 code back from the API, so obviously I'm doing something very wrong here.

I would've used the python-binance wrapper for inspiration, but unfortunately I can barely grasp how that code functions.

Could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Here is the link to the binance API documentation:
https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md

```
def makeBuy(side, symbol, quantity, price):
    timestamp = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    queryS = "symbol=" + symbol + "&side=" + side + "&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=" + \
         str(quantity) + "&price=" + str(price) + "&timestamp=" + str(timestamp)
    m = hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), queryS.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256)
    url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order?' + queryS + '&signature=' + str(m.hexdigest())

    response2 = requests.get(url, headers={'X-MBX-APIKEY': api_key})
    print(response2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out how to do it through trial and error:

```
     def makeBuy(side, symbol, quantity, price):
        timestamp = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
        queryS = "symbol=" + symbol + "&side=" + side + "&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=" + \
    str(quantity) + "&price=" + str(price) + "&timestamp=" + str(timestamp)
        m = hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), queryS.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256)
        header = {'X-MBX-APIKEY' : api_key}
        url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order' + '?' + queryS + '&signature=' + m.hexdigest()
        response2 = requests.post(url, headers=header, timeout=30, verify=True)
        print(response2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you access the api via a web browser and use the network advanced options of the browser (preferably chrome)  to see the exact cookies and structure of the get request and the try to achieve the same using python. 
I was facing a similar problem last week and that's how I solved it.